# cannot increment a localStorage value

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, impactjs

I am trying to increment my localStorage value every time a condition in if statement is true but it seems I am not able to do it right. Tried everything possible. Here is my code that does the check and increments the value.

```
for(var j = 0; j < inputArray.length; j++){
    for(var k = 0; k < this.probsSolved.length; k++){
        if(inputArray[k] == this.probsSolved[j] ){

            //increment the localStorage value here

            **this.storage.set(probSolKey,parseInt(this.storage.get(probSolKey)) + 1);**

            if(this.storage.get(probSolKey) >= totalProbToSolve){
                this.storage.set(achkey,1);
                this.triggerAchievements(id,name);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So I have a localStorage plugin for ImpactJS engine which I am using. I am trying to increment probSolKey which I pass in my function as a parameter String. Whenever the condition is met I try to increment itself by 1. I don't know how to implement this correctly. Anyone help me out on this, will really appreciate it!

Doing some debugging i found out this:

```
console.log(this.storage.get(probSolKey));
```

Throws a weird value of "NaN".

Answer (score 0):

When you stored the value of the property you're trying to increment, you thought you stored a number, but you actually didn't.

You stored a value that was suposed to be a number so it was converted to one, but the conversion failed because the value couldn't be parsed as a number.

That's what NaN stands for, Not a Number, something that couldn't be parsed as a number.

Comment: nope, it does not work. :(
when i do console.log("counter " +this.storage.get(probSolKey))
it gives counter NaN as output and does not increment the value. Any idea?

Comment: could you do a console.log(this.storage.get(probSolKey) and tell us what you get?

Comment: Sure the console.log(this.storage.get(probSolKey)) throws a weird value of "NaN". I don't know what that means!

Comment: NaN stands for Not A Number, and it's what you get when trying to convert some value to a number, and the conversion fails. So you're getting that because whenever you stored the value, you thought you were storing a number, but you stored something that was suposed to be a number, but couldn't be parsed as one.

Comment: Okay I somehow tried to compare my value to "NaN".concat(value), changed the if statement

if(this.storage.get(probSolKey) ==  "NaN".concat(totalProbToSolve))

It compares fine but only for the first instance ie I get NaN1 as my value on the first time the condition is true but next time when the condition is true my localStorage value stays at NaN1 and not NaN2

This is what I did as you suggested

this.storage.set(probSolKey,'' +parseInt(this.storage.get(probSolKey))+1);

Comment: Of course, you need to solve the initial value storage, this means, store a value thats actually a number instead of something that's going to be parsed as NaN, because when you add 1 to 'NaN1' you get 'NaN11', because the + operator will always perform concatenation if there is a string present in the operation. I understand if you're lost here.

Comment: If the initial value for the porperties should be 0, use this: if(this.storage.get(probSolKey) == "NaN") this.storage.set(probSolKey, 1); else this.storage.set(probSolKey, parseInt(this.storage.get(probSolKey)) + 1);  This code should work if and only if, the starting value to increment is 0. If this is not the case then definitly you'll need to fix the issue storing a number instead of something that will be parsed to NaN before you increment it.